# Amazon Lex accepting ConfirmIntent on any response

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have an `intent-A` which is triggered by some user input. When the response is given to user I have used `ConfirmIntent` instead of `Close` so that I can switch/chain another intent (lets say `intent-B`).

Ideally if user type `"yes"` then intent should be triggered and if user type `"no"` then it should not. Problem is that `intent-B` is being triggered no matter what I type.

I have read about `ConfirmIntent` from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html), [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/book-trip-detail-flow.html).

**Calling Code:**

```
session_attributes = {"confirmationContext": "AutoPopulate"}
return confirm_intent(session_attributes , 'intent-B', slots, 'Do you want to invoke intent-B')
```

**ConfirmIntent Code:**

```
def confirm_intent(session_attributes, intent_name, slots, message):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ConfirmIntent',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'message': {
                'contentType': 'PlainText',
                'content': message
            }
        }
    }
```

In the logs I can see that `confirmationStatus': 'Denied'` when I type `"no`" but even then `intent-B` is being called.

Am I missing something or is it designed this way?

**NOTE:** For workaround I am adding below code in the DialogCodeHook of `intent-B`

```
if 'confirmationStatus' in intent_request['currentIntent'] and intent_request['currentIntent']['confirmationStatus'] == 'Denied':
    return close("Ok, let me know if you need anything else.", session_attributes)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are handling this correctly.

When you are passing `intent-B` into your `confirm_intent` request. You are telling Lex to pass the users response to `intent-B`. When the user responds with `"no"`, the `Denied` value is correctly passed on.

Alternatively, you could have `intent-A` in your `confirm_intent` request. Then when the response hits `intent-A` you can use `Close` on denial and `Delegate` on `confirmation` to pass the flow to `intent-B`. This is "more correct" but will result in additional computation, so it's a trade off.

If you have multiple follow up requests, you could consider using `ElicitIntent` to instead ask the user `"What can I help you with?"`. Having an an intent with utterances such as `"nothing"`, `"goodbye"` will catch negative responses. This is a slightly different use case and may not be appropriate for you.

Comment: so the intent-B will always be called but we can stop it's execution in DialogCodeHook by validating "confirmationStatus". is that correct?

Comment: @sid8491 I've added another approach you can use using `Delegate` to only call `intent-B` when required. This is more computationally expensive so it's your call if you think it's a better way

Comment: Hi @Milk, `confirmationStatus` is being set to `Confirmed` even if I type some single words like **outlook**, **printer** etc which are nowhere closer to **yes**. how to resolve this... any idea?