# Calling from one intent to another intent in AWS LEX

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bots, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am a newbie in the AWS arena. Now I am working on AWS LEX. I want to call from one intent to another intent. I have found the following question but as I cannot comment I have created another one.

[How to call Intent B from intent A in AWS lex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147655/how-to-call-intent-b-from-intent-a-in-aws-lex)

1. My question is where will I put the codes of the 1st method from the above link?
2. How to call a lambda function from a intent and what is the code format in JavaScript?

Comment: Hello @sid8491 can you please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is where will i put the codes of the 1st method from the
>   above link?

When the intent-A is called and you are responding back to user, at that time you will use that code. Basically instead of `dialogAction` type `Close` we are using `ConfirmIntent`.
You can read more about response format [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format).

**Complete code:**

```
def build_response(message):
    return {
        "dialogAction":{
            "type":"Close",
            "fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
            "message":{
                "contentType":"PlainText",
                "content":message
            }
        }
    }

def delegate(session_attributes, slots):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Delegate',
            'slots': slots
        }
    }

def confirm_intent(session_attributes, intent_name, slots, message):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ConfirmIntent',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'message': {
                'contentType': 'PlainText',
                'content': message
            }
        }
    }

def perform_action_A(intent_request):
    source = intent_request['invocationSource']
    output_session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
    slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    # whatever you want to do
    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        # Perform basic validation on the supplied input slots.
        return delegate(output_session_attributes, slots)

    if source == 'FulfillmentCodeHook':
        # action fulfillment code
        msg = "Hi, I am a xxx-BOT. i can help you with following: A B C"
        return confirm_intent(output_session_attributes, 'intent-B', slots, msg)


def perform_action_B(intent_request):
    # some code
    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        # Perform basic validation on the supplied input slots.
        return delegate(output_session_attributes, slots)
    if source == 'FulfillmentCodeHook':
        # action fulfillment code
        build_response('Final close message')


def dispatch(intent_request):
    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']
    # Dispatch to your bot's intent handlers
    if intent_name == 'intent-A':
        return perform_action_A(intent_request)
    if intent_name == 'intent-B':
        return perform_action_B(intent_request)
    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.debug(event)
    return dispatch(event)
```

> How to call a lambda function from a intent and what is the code
>   format in javascript?

I have not coded any lex bot in javascript, maybe [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html) might help you.

**Test Event Code:**

```
{
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "intent-A",
    "slots": {
    }
  },
  "invocationSource": "DialogCodeHook",
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "bot": {
    "name": "Your_Bot_Name"
  },
  "userId": "Some_User_Id"
}
```

For Fulfillment change the value of `invocationSource` to `FulfillmentCodeHook`. Also, give the slots if there are any.

Just to clarify, `configure test events` is used for testing the Lambda code by simulating a request. You can directly integrate the Lambda function with Lex and test using Lex console.

Hope it helps.

**Edit 1:** Updated the answer with code.
**Edit 2:** Updated test events code.

Comment: in Configure test event which Intent detail i should put....Current Intent-A or new Intent-B

Comment: @TAMIMHAIDER in `configure test event` you should write general sentence/utterance which will invoke `intent-A`. i have updated the answer with code as well. do check.

Comment: as i have understood i can use this lambda function in both of "Lambda initialization and validation" and "Fullfillment". I just need to select the name of this lambda function. Is is possible to give the sample of "configure test event". As a newbie i have lots of confusions. TIA

Comment: @TAMIMHAIDER check the updated answer, `Lambda initialization and validation` will invoke `DialogCodeHook` and `Fullfillment` will invoke `FulfillmentCodeHook`. And configure test events is used to simulate a request being made to Lambda, you can directly test it using Lex that will be simpler i think.

Comment: i am getting the ConfirmIntent message from current Intent (A). But as per logic simultaneously my second Intent need to trigger. But how can i come to know , the second Intent (B) is triggered successfully?

Comment: @TAMIMHAIDER after getting `confirmIntent` message, you have to type yes/no, based on that intent-B will be called, to verify you can `log` something in intent-B or simply reply with some message from intent-B.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811275/amazon-lex-accepting-confirmintent-on-any-response read this as well for better understanding

Comment: come to the chat

Comment: Intent-B is triggered successfully but getting error on Intent-B, Added the error message and lambda function code for the newly called Intent. See the last part of your Answer

Comment: Is `DialogAction` possible only when using Lambda functions?

Comment: @Dinesh what do you mean?

Comment: @sid8491 In my app I also process partially-filled intents, akin to filling out a jigsaw puzzle. So I use aws-sdk and `AWS.LexRuntime.postContent` but there is no documentation addressing `dialogAction` property. Afterwards I read that this is available only for lambda users.

Comment: @Dinesh `postContent` is used fr sending a message to the bot. `dialogaction` is used for generating a reply back from the bot, that reply can be a prompt to ask some slot or a close message. it will be defined in the webhook you will provide to the bot, it can be lambda function